# Check checkboxes based on URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, checkbox, decodeuricomponent

I am trying to check various checkboxes on a form based on parameters found in the URL.

The URL could resemble something like this:

```
https://development.mycompany.com/project/home.php?profile=profile1,profle2&region=&rep=
```

As you will see, the "profile" parameter in the URL has two values (profile1, profile2).

I have a form that has a series of checkboxes that looks like this:

```
<input class="profileCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="PROFILE1CHECK" name="profileCheckbox" value="PROFILE1" />
<input class="profileCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="PROFILE2CHECK" name="profileCheckbox" value="PROFILE2" />
<input class="profileCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="PROFILE3CHECK" name="profileCheckbox" value="PROFILE3" />
// few more
```

Using the URL parameters, the checkbox ID's PROFILE1CHECK and PROFILE2CHECK should be checked, leaving any other checkboxes unchecked.

I have this piece of codes that grabs any parameters found in the URL:

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    
    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
      return typeof sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
    }
  }
  return false;
};

var profile = getUrlParameter('profile');

console.log(profile);
```

When I console the profile variable, I can see the following:

```
profile1,profile2
```

This is where I got stuck.

I'm not really sure how to check the checkboxes for the ID's for PROFILE1CHECK and PROFILE2CHECK.

Comment: var profile = getUrlParameter('profile');
$("#profile1CheckboxId").attr("checked",profile.indexOf("profile1") !== -1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var profile = getUrlParameter('profile');
$("#PROFILE1CHECK").attr("checked",profile.indexOf("profile1") !== -1);
```